# Why does this XQuery not work?

Tags: datetime, xquery

```
 let $ds := cts:search(
      fn:doc(),
      cts:and-query(
       (            
         cts:collection-query(('InProgress_Audit'))
       )
      )) where not(contains( $ds//TitleDate/text(), "Z"))

      return count($ds)
```

The TitleDate nodes contain date times.

Returns:

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004)
>   fn:contains((fn:doc("/icis.dnr.audit.issue/E-STY/E-STY_201212072330_20121207164208.xml")/ProductIssue/TitleDate/text(),
>   fn:doc("/icis.dnr.audit.issue/E-TIO2-EU/E-TIO2-EU_201303090245_20130307145047.xml")/ProductIssue/TitleDate/text(),
>   fn:doc("/icis.dnr.audit.issue/F-ETHY/F-ETHY_201302221700_20130222055846.xml")/ProductIssue/TitleDate/text(), ...), "Z") -- arg1 is not of type xs:string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ds//TitleDate/text()` returns multiple items, while `contains(...)` only allows a single string as first parameter.

Move contains into a predicate, so it is called for every single input:

```
not($ds//TitleDate/text()[contains(., "Z")])
```